# 'time sleep function' makes problem in the changing videos loop

Tags: python, loops, video, raspberry-pi3, playback

I am a beginner and 
I made a code for Video trigger loop in Raspberry Pi by using ultrasonic sensor, but problem is that the videos ('movie1' and 'movie2') can not instantly changed depend on the distance. I guess, this problem is caused by time.sleep function, but when I delete the sleep parts, my code didn't work and even Raspberry pi is shutdown. How can I fix this problem? If you have any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks!

I considered about 'datetime function' instead of 'time.sleep', but i don't have any idea how to put the function in my code.

```
while True:
        dist = distance()
        time.sleep(1)

        if (distance() <= 100):
            zone = 1
        if (distance() >= 2000):
            zone = 1
        elif (100 < distance() < 2000):
            zone = 2

        if (zone == 1):
            Popen(['/usr/bin/omxplayer', '--display','0', movie1])
            time.sleep(6)

        if (zone == 2):
            Popen(['/usr/bin/omxplayer', '--display','0', movie2])
            time.sleep(6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you delete `time.sleep(6)` code open movie1 over and over. you can try add a controll statement for break the infinit loop like:

```
zone1,zone2=True,True #before the loop

if (distance() <= 100):
    zone = 1
if (distance() >= 2000):
    zone = 1
elif (100 < distance() < 2000):
    zone = 2

if (zone == 1 and zone1):
    Popen('killall "omxplayer.bin"',shell=True)
    Popen(['/usr/bin/omxplayer', '--display','0', movie1])
    zone1=False
    zone2=True

if (zone == 2 and zone2):
    Popen('killall "omxplayer.bin"',shell=True)
    Popen(['/usr/bin/omxplayer', '--display','0', movie2])
    zone2=False
    zone1=True
```

*or*

i suggest you to play video in python. idk if works with raspberry pi but opencv is good for this job

Comment: Thank you for answering! But when I run the code, two videos are blink and overlapping and after few seconds, even stop working. So i check the raspberry pi terminal, I saw that 'tvservice-client: Failed to connect to TV service: -1
', 'omxplayer.bin: OMXCore.cpp:786: OMX_ERRORTYPE COMXCoreComponent::FreeInputBuffers(): Assertion `m_omx_input_buffers.size() == m_omx_input_avaliable.size()' failed.'

Comment: just try the execute Popen(['/usr/bin/omxplayer', '--display','0', movie1])

Comment: sorry, You mean.. delete the 'Popen(['/usr/bin/omxplayer', '--display','0', movie2])' part and just execute first part?

Comment: no just execute 'Popen(['/usr/bin/omxplayer', '--display','0', movie2])' part see if its true and give my vote we fix your question

Comment: When I execute only 'Popen(['/usr/bin/omxplayer', '--display','0', movie2])', the video was played very well without any other error

Comment: edited! add a killall omxplayer before start this time player wont run multiple times

Comment: add a 'os.system('killall omxplayer.bin')' in before the while loop?

Comment: i edited my answer look up. Popen("killall omxplayer")

Comment: sorry but When I edited like your code, I got a error like #OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory'

Comment: i dont have a raspberry pi sorry but you should find a way to quit omxplayer instead of Popen("killall omxplayer") lines

Comment: can you replace Popen("killall omxplayer") lines to Popen('killall "omxplayer.bin"')

Comment: Thank you so much! but even I edited 'Popen("killall omxplayer")' lines to 'Popen('killall "omxplayer.bin"')', until I got some error like   
File "ultrasonic5.py", line 77, in <module>
    Popen('killall "omxplayer.bin"')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: oh i got it you need to use shell true parameter new lines are Popen('killall "omxplayer.bin"', shell=True)

Comment: yes and zone1,zone2=True,True line must be placed before the loop